# Does a client have to disconnect from the server in order for another client to connect? Python sockets

Tags: python, tcp

I am trying to connect to sensor #1(the sensor has amplifier that you can communicate with via tcp/ip) that is on the network that both my laptop and the PLC are on. I have already successfully connected to sensors #2 & 3 on the machine which the PLC is not sending requests to but I cannot get a response from sensor #1 which the PLC is actively communicating with. Is it necessary when connecting to a server that you need to disconnect from it in order for another client to connect to it and make a request? I have attached a sample program I made to verify whether my connections to each sensor are successful but my connection to sensor #1 is never successful as it never responds

```
import socket
import time
import sys

client1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client3 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client1.connect(('192.168.3.22', 8500)) #Sensor 2
client2.connect(('192.168.3.23', 8500)) #Sensor 3
client3.connect(('192.168.3.21', 8500)) #Sensor 1
print(client1)
print(client2)
print(client3)

status_result_reading="RT\r"

client1.send(bytes(status_result_reading,'ascii'))
client2.send(bytes(status_result_reading,'ascii'))
client3.send(bytes(status_result_reading,'ascii'))
time.sleep(.2)
msg1 = client1.recv(200)
msg2 = client2.recv(200)
#msg3 = client3.recv(200)
#print(msg1.decode('ascii')+'\t'+msg2.decode('ascii')+'\t'+msg3.decode('ascii'))
print(msg1.decode('ascii')+'\t'+msg2.decode('ascii'))


#Disconnect from the robot and close the socket object
client1.close()
client2.close()
client3.close()
print('close')
sys.exit()
```

.

Comment: Technically the 3 sensors are servers, as you're connecting to them. Each has it's own address. Whether a sensor can handle more than one client or not will be up to the developer of the webservice running on it - I doubt anyone here can help you with that. This seems to be an issue with the specific sensor that's not responding (and how you should communicate with it)

Comment: ok thank you, I already reached out to the vendor but I thought I would see if anyone could maybe help

Comment: The general answer is no, disconnection is not required. The key item, concept, missing is threading.  Add threading, import threading, and become familiar with it. The server can then just continually listen for messages.

Comment: Just think of Google (or StackOverflow). Many people are talking to the same server at the same time. Servers can set a limit on the number of open connections and pending connections, but that’s all under the server’s control.